# How do you use a Node.js variable on the client-side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, html

I'm relative new to NODEJS and I'm struggling with a basic problem, which is the correct use of global variables, I read a lot about it but it seems I can't make it work properly, I'll post some codes for a better view of the problem.

I have this simple js running as a server:

**myapi.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;
var fs = require('fs');
var jUptime;
var ipExp = require('./getDown');
var filesD = [];
var path = "/media/pi/01D16F03D7563070/movies";

app.use(express['static'](__dirname ));

exec("sudo /sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'", function(error, stdout, stderr){
            ip = stdout;
            exports.ipAdd = ip;
            console.log(ip);
});

app.get('/files', function(req, res) {
    fs.readdir(path, function(err, files) {
        if (err){
            console.log("Non riesco a leggere i files");
        }

        filesD=files;
        console.log(filesD);

    });
    res.status(200).send(filesD);
});

app.get('/up', function(req, res) {
    child = exec("uptime -p", function(error, stdout, stderr){
                    jUptime = [{uptime: stdout}];
                });
    res.status(200).send(jUptime);
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).send('Richiesta non riconosciuta');
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if (req.xhr) {
        res.status(500).send('Qualcosa è andato storto');
    } else {
        next(err);
    }
});
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server attivo sulla porta 3000');
```

And then I have this JS used in a simple web page:

**getDown.js**

```
var ip = require('./myapi').ipAdd;
function gDownloads() {
    var url;
    var jqxhr;
    var dat;

        url = 'http://' + ip + '/files';
        jqxhr = $.getJSON(url, function(dat) {
        for(i=0; i<dat.length; i++){
                    $('#downLoad').append('<p>' + dat[i] + '</p>');
        }
        $('#bId').append(dat.length);
        })
     .done(function() {
        console.log("OK");
     })
     .fail(function(data) {
        console.log("Fallito: "+data);
     })
};
```

The problem is that when I navigate to the html page that use getDown.js I get the following error on getDown.js

```
require is not defined
```

I need to pass the variable that contains the IP address in myapi.js to use it in getDown.js, I hope I explain myself good enough, thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot `require` your node scripts from browser unless you use something like `browserify`

Comment: Fundamental misunderstanding here: Your NodeJS code is running *on the server*. Your web page code is running *on the client*. The error you're getting ("require is not defined") is because `require` isn't something that browsers currently offer, unless you use an AMD plugin, and even if you did you don't want to include your **server-side** code in the **client-side** web page.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that makes sense, so how can I acomplish what I'm trying to do? I thought to make a REST call and get a json with the IP, but I would really like to avoid using a call for that.

Answer (score 0):

`require` is global that exists in Node.js code, that is, on the javascript code executing in the server.

Your server will respond to the client and give it an HTML page to render. That HTML page could tell the browser to also request a javascript file from the server. When it receives that file, the client will execute it. The client does *not* have a `require` global (you can test it by opening up the console and typing `require`)

### Using Browserify

Or you can write Node-style code, requiring your global like you're doing, but then run the code through [browserify](http://browserify.org/). This will create a new javascript bundle that can be executed by the client, so you should tell your html page to use that bundle instead of `getDown.js`.

Here is a basic example of doing using browserify like this.

#### *module.js*

```
function getIp() {
  return 123456;
}

module.exports = {
  getIp: getIp
};
```

#### *main.js*

```
var module = require('./module');

function getIp() {
  var ip = module.getIp();
  return ip;
};

console.log(getIp());
```

#### *compile bundle*

```
$ browserify main.js -o public/bundle.js
```

#### *index.html*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/bundle.js"></script>
```

### Global variable on the client

To use a global variable on the client which is known by the server, you can pass that variable to your rendering engine (possibly Jade if you're using Express) and have it interpolate that variable into a `<script>` tag which defines some globals. Leave a comment if that's the approach you'd prefer and I can add some more details.

Let me know if you have more questions!

Comment: Hi and thanks, I would prefer to use browserify, I installed it via npm and tryin' to use it but I'm "fighting a lot" to make it work properly, can you please modify my above code so I can understand it? I followed the exact procedure in the tutorial from Browserify homepage included in the HTML file the bundle.js but after the html parser comes to my <script src="bundle.js"> the parse throws an error: Cannot read the property 'prototype' of undefined... buff...I just need to use a variable in my server-side code..I didn't expect was that hard!

Comment: I don't think I can debug why your code is throwing that without being able to run it and debug it. If you want you could publish it github and post a link, but what I can do now is post a basic example of using browserify.